# Azure Data Factory Storage Event Trigger - Access full URL of blob

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there any way to access the full blob url from an ADF storage event trigger?

The docs say that there is only `folderName` and `filePath`, but when I look at the actual payload of the event trigger (in Monitor -> Trigger Runs), I can see the full URL there:

```
 {
  "topic": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxx",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/yyy/blobs/zzz.snappy.parquet",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
  "id": "xxx",
  "data": {
    "api": "PutBlob",
    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "blobUrl": "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/yyy/zzz.snappy.parquet",
    "url": "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/yyy/zzz.snappy.parquet"
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1",
  "eventTime": "2021-06-09T23:00:00.0000000Z"
}
```

I tried to follow this post's advice and looked at the full contents of `@{trigger()}`, but it only contains a `RunToken`:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
    "Host": "xxx.westus2.logic.azure.com",
    "Content-Length": "975",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  "body": {
    "RunToken": "long-string=="
  }
}
```

Comment: I am also having this problem. Did you ever find a solution or documentation that explains this behaviour?

Comment: I did not unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you got `@{trigger()}` expression from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/46331/processing-azure-data-factory-event-trigger-proper.html. Now it can't work. As you said, you can only get RunToken in triggerBody. By now, there is no way to get file's fully URL from event trigger.

Answer (score 0):

we can get the full url using an object type pipeline parameter and initializing it with "@trigger().outputs.body.event" which will give the full url output in object type.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/46331/processing-azure-data-factory-event-trigger-proper