# ADF Blob Trigger does not have @triggerBody().folderPath

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-trigger

I followed the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger? to create a pipeline and trigger but when I add a new file the trigger @triggerBody().folderPath and @triggerBody().fileName

in the body of the trigger looks like this:

```
{
"outputs": {
    "body": {
        "RunToken": "AAEAFO....."
    },
    "headers": {
        ...
    }
},
"originHistoryName": "08585080678291936867780979968CU85",
"endTime": "2023-09-01T03:30:56.2837211Z",
"status": "Succeeded",
"startTime": "2023-09-01T03:30:56.2837211Z",
"clientTrackingId": ".....",
"name": "Trigger_421B8CAF-BE66-42CF-83DA-E3028693F304",
"trackingId": "....."
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you add the error and exact issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@triggerBody().folderPath` and `@triggerBody().filename` are the properties which fetch the folder path and file name respectively. there is no way to get these values in the trigger body it will just give run token and some other properties refer this similar [SO queation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68031970)

**When you add these properties as a value to your pipeline parameters it will fetch that value from trigger run and assign it to your pipeline parameter**

There is event load for the trigger which provides you all this information like metadata of blob to get that you can use this trigger run property `@trigger().outputs.body.event`

It will give you output like below:

```json
{
  "TriggerTime": "09/04/2023 12:26:53",
  "EventPayload": {
                  "topic": "/subscriptions/Id/resourceGroups/resource group name/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/dlsg2p",   
                  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/pratik/blobs/ParentFolder/SubFolder01/csv1.csv",
                  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
                  "id": "d3c52f27-601f-0028-442b-dfa9de06fe0c",
                  "data": {
                      "api": "FlushWithClose",
                      "requestId": "d3c52f27-601f-0028-442b-dfa9de000000",
                      "eTag":"0x8DBAD4237409006",
                      "contentType":"application/octet-stream",
                      "contentLength": 33,"contentOffset": 0,
                      "blobType": "BlockBlob",
                      "blobUrl": "https://dlsg2p.blob.core.windows.net/pratik/ParentFolder/SubFolder01/csv1.csv",
                      "url": "https://dlsg2p.dfs.core.windows.net/pratik/ParentFolder/SubFolder01/csv1.csv",
                      "sequencer": "0000000000000000000000000001e5460000000000010361",
                      "identity": "$superuser",
                      "storageDiagnostics": {
                          "batchId": "e672ea68-1006-0068-002b-df8030000000"}},
"dataVersion": "3",
"metadataVersion": "1",
"eventTime": "2023-09-04T12:26:50.9512037Z"}
}
```

**here we are getting filename and folder path:**

[image]